# Using Tkinter and suprocess.call

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, gdal

I would like to use tkinter to open a window that will allow a user to select two separate files that will be manipulated several times within my script. I am having trouble finding a way to set the file that will be selected using the button in my tkinter window as a variable so that it can be used within subprocess.call. I have found invoke() but it doesn't seem to have any affect. Any ideas on what I might do would be greatly appreciated.

```
import os
import sys
import gdal
from gdalconst import *
import numpy as np
import math
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import math
import datetime
import shutil
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


newpath = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Float32')
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)
newpath_2 = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Zeros')
if not os.path.exists(newpath_2):
    os.makedirs(newpath_2)
newpath_3 = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\db_Files')
if not os.path.exists(newpath_3):
    os.makedirs(newpath_3)


if __name__== '__main__':

    # Set all of the necessary constants so that the script can create and save the pertinent files
    # on the users desktop

    #tk1 = Tk()
    #tk2 = Tk()
    #callTK = 'src_dataset =' + tk1
    #callTK_2 = 'srcVH =' + tk2
    gdalTranslate = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_translate.exe'
    tk1.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(text="Open HV File")
    tk2.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(text="Open VH File")
    dst_dataset = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Float32\\newHV32.img')
    dstVH = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Float32\\newVH32.img')
    sttime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('(Time_Run = %Y-%d-%m_%H:%M:%S)')
    wheel_install_1 = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Sigma_Test\\wheel_install.py')
    wheel_install_2 = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Sigma_Test\\wheel_install2.py')
    ridofz = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Sigma_Test\\ridofZsv2.py')
    to_dB = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Sigma_Test\\to_dBv2.py')
    db_HV = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\dB_Files\\newHVdB.img')
    db_VH = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\dB_Files\\newVHdB.img')
    cmd = "-ot float32 -of HFA" # hopefully this works


    # Install necessary packages, which are GDAL and Numpy

   # try:
        #os.system(wheel_install_1)
        #print ("GDAL intalled")
        #os.system(wheel_install_2)
        #print ("Numpy installed")

    #except:
        #print ("The packages are't installing properly")
        #sys.exit()

    # Create three new folders which will house the files that will be created
    # along each sequential step of the script

    #newpath = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Float32')
    #if not os.path.exists(newpath):
        #os.makedirs(newpath)
    #newpath_2 = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Zeros')
    #if not os.path.exists(newpath_2):
        #os.makedirs(newpath_2)
    #newpath_3 = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\db_Files')
    #if not os.path.exists(newpath_3):
        #os.makedirs(newpath_3)

    root = Tk()
    #root.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    root.title("Utilis Sigma Test")
    root.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\jack.UTILIS\Desktop\images\sigma.ico")
    root.configure(background="#179EBB")
    topFrame = Frame(root)
    topFrame.pack()

    photo = PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\jack.UTILIS\\Desktop\\images\\Utilis_Branding2015_FINAL_Small.gif")
    label = Label(root, image=photo)
    label.pack(side=RIGHT)

    bottomFrame = Frame(root)
    bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)


    button1 = Button(root, text="Open HV File", fg="black",   command=filedialog.askopenfilename)
    button2 = Button(root, text="Open VH FIle", fg="black", command=filedialog.askopenfilename)


    button1.pack(side=LEFT)
    button2.pack(side=RIGHT)



    hvfullCmd = ' '.join([gdalTranslate, cmd, tk1.fileName,dst_dataset])
    subprocess.call(hvfullCmd)
    vhfullCmd = ' '.join([gdalTranslate,cmd, tk2.fileName,dstVH])
    subprocess.call(vhfullCmd)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you have to assign to button (`command=`) own function which use `filedialog.askopenfilename` to get filename and does something with this name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create own function which get filename from `askopenfilename` and does something with this file. Then you can assign this file to button using `command=`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

# --- functions ---

def on_click():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if filename:
        print("Filename:", filename)
    else:
        print("Filename: not selected")

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Click Me', command=on_click)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```